# Check current URL is 404 in pre_option_stylesheet filter hook

Tags: plugin-development, urls, 404-error

I am trying to check the current url is `404` or not in the `pre_option_stylesheet` filter hook. As this is the early hook called by wordpress, due to which wordpress default function like `is_404` not works. It generates a notice saying:

> Notice: is_404 was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in D:\xamp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\functions.php on line 5229

I also tried to check 404 by using `curl()`, `wp_remote_post()`, `@get_headers($url)` but none of these worked for me.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What's the problem you're trying to solve that requires this? There's almost certainly a better/simpler solution. Also you should not use the `@` operator, it is very bad practice. `@` does not fix errors, it silences them, the error still occurs if you use `@` it's just not reported to logs

Comment: I have to use different installed theme on 404 page which is not the active theme. For this purpose i have to check 404 condition on  `pre_option_stylesheet` filter hook.

Comment: Why? Just use the `404.php` template in the theme and register different styles and scripts, or better yet just match the `.error404` class on the body tag in your stylesheet. If you want your 404 page to look different to the rest of your site, you should ask about that, but loading a completely separate theme is a huge task with lots of unanticipated consequences

Comment: I managed unanticipated consequences of loading a separate theme. It is not just for 404 page but for rest of the pages. I have added option to select different theme on a each page/post. It would not affect rest of the website rather run multiple themes on pages. I managed for pages and posts but the only issue i am facing is with 404 page.

Comment: How are you doing that though? It's a rather extreme thing to do but there's no code or technical information in your question about how it works

Comment: Is there a way to check if current url is rewritten url or not?

Comment: That's easy, check if the URL ends in `.php`, otherwise all URLs are rewritten, but that's not going to solve your 404 problem. The canonical answer to this, is to use the `error404` HTML class in an existing stylesheet. That filter is too early to use `is_404`, WP does not know if it's a 404 yet. Anybody who wanted to change that will need to know how you changed the theme, which is why I asked, it's a super important thing that you should have mentioned and shared in your question. It's very likely that a normal answer would not work for you because of this, that's why i asked for code